# Bootstrap table not paginating

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

While following online tutorials, I implemented the following simple html code with Bootstrap in the hopes I would get pagination, a search bar, among other things:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap- 
table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/bootstrap- 
table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.3/dist/locale/bootstrap- 
table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>

<title>HTML Tables Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h4 class="text-center">This is a test</h4>
    <table data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thread>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="col1">col1</th>
        <th data-field="col2">col2</th>
        <th data-field="col3">col3</th>
    </tr>
    </thread>

    <tr>
    <td>Russell Westbrook</td>
    <td>OKC</td>
    <td>2558</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Michael Jordan</td>
    <td>Chicago</td>
    <td>3214</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.display').DataTable();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As we can see here, just a simple table with 2 records. Visually:
[image]

It appears to "sort of" work, as the text font changes (so I know that bootstrap is at least being loaded in) but as we can see in the above screenshot, pagination is not enforced and there is no search bar, despite being implemented.

Plainly, given my lack of experience - why exactly is the search bar & table pagination not taking effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default length for pagination is 10. Try

```
data-pagination="true"
data-page-size="1"
```

...or try with more than two rows. You can find the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#pagesize).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The linked documentation sorted things :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataTable js](https://datatables.net/blog/2011-08-27) , is best for table with all future , try this

Comment: Why is it better and how does it answer the question?

Comment: DataTable is better because one target and fast and easy to use